# IndexError out of range but list element still prints

Tags: python, indexing, beautifulsoup

I'm using bs4 to scrape some data and my code seems to be fine but I'm receiving a random IndexError after it runs smoothly.

CODE

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get(f'https://www.espn.com/nba/schedule/_/date/{d2}')

soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')

tables = soup.findAll('table', {'class': 'schedule has-team-logos align-left'})

def spreads():
    for table in tables:
        link = table.find('a', {'name': '&lpos=nba:schedule:time'})
        hreff = link['href']

        r = requests.get(f'https://www.espn.com{hreff}')
        soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')

        pickCenter = soup.find('div', {'class': 'pick-center-content'})
        spreadMLs = soup.findAll('td', {'class': 'score'})
        
        city = soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'long-name'})
        name = soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'short-name'})

        team1 = f'{city[0].text} {name[0].text}'
        team2 = f'{city[1].text} {name[1].text}'

        spread1 = spreadMLs[15].text
        spread2 = spreadMLs[16].text

        mL1 = spreadMLs[17].text
        mL2 = spreadMLs[18].text

        print(f'Betting Lines & Odds\n')

        print('Spread: ')
        print(f'{team1} {spread1}')
        print(f'{team2} {spread2}')

spreads()
```

OUTPUT

```
Betting Lines & Odds

Spread:
Minnesota Timberwolves +3.5
Charlotte Hornets -3.5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Code/nba.py", line 48, in <module>
    spreads()
  File "c:/Users/Code/nba.py", line 36, in spreads
    spread1 = spreadMLs[15].text
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How is the index out of range when it's clearly reading and printing it?

Comment: There is probably an index error in the second iteration of your for loop. Use a debugger to check where it happens.
The reason it prints is because the first iteration of the loop is probably just fine.

Comment: `for table in tables` ... The first table is working fine and printing something; the second is failing before it gets that far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple tables being returned by your `tables` variable.
In the first iteration of the `for table in tables` loop there is likely no issue since the table prints, however, the second iteration of the loop is meeting an error.

If you only need the first table returned I recommend changing your `tables` variable to `tables = soup.find('table', {'class': 'schedule has-team-logos align-left'})`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use espn's api to grab that. It's all there (and more), just need to parse it.

```
import requests

url = 'http://site.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/basketball/nba/scoreboard'

jsonData = requests.get(url).json()
events = jsonData['events']

print(f'Betting Lines & Odds')
for event in events:
    competition = event['competitions'][0]
    odds = competition['odds'][0]['details']
    ou = competition['odds'][0]['overUnder']
    team_abbrv, spread = odds.split()
    spread = float(spread)
    
    print('\nSpread: ')
    competitors = competition['competitors']
    for each in competitors:
        team = each['team']['displayName']
        if each['team']['abbreviation'] == team_abbrv:
            odd = spread*(-1)
        else:
            odd = spread
        print(f'{team} {odd}')
    print(f'O/U: {ou}')
```

Or there's also the websites header api too:

```
import requests

url = 'https://site.web.api.espn.com/apis/v2/scoreboard/header'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36'}
payload = {
'sport': 'basketball',
'league': 'nba',
'region': 'us',
'lang': 'en',
'contentorigin': 'espn',
'buyWindow': '1m',
'showAirings': 'buy,live,replay',
'showZipLookup': 'true',
'tz': 'America/New_York'}

data = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()

# find the spread for the games
games = data['sports'][0]['leagues'][0]['events']
print(f'Betting Lines & Odds')
for game in games:
    teams = game['competitors']
    for team in teams:
        if team['homeAway'] == 'home':
            homeTeam = team['abbreviation']
            homeTeamName = team['displayName']
        if team['homeAway'] == 'away':
            awayTeam = team['abbreviation']
            awayTeamName = team['displayName']
    odds = game['odds']['spread']
    ou = game['odds']['overUnder']
    print('\nSpread: ')
    print('%s %s' %(homeTeamName, odds))
    print('%s %s' %(awayTeamName, odds*-1))
    print('O/U: %s' %ou)
```

**Output:**

```
Betting Lines & Odds

Spread: 
Charlotte Hornets 3.5
Minnesota Timberwolves -3.5
O/U: 228.5

Spread: 
Washington Wizards -2.5
New York Knicks 2.5
O/U: 219.0

Spread: 
Atlanta Hawks 2.0
San Antonio Spurs -2.0
O/U: 225.5

Spread: 
Dallas Mavericks 3.0
New Orleans Pelicans -3.0
O/U: 232.0

Spread: 
Chicago Bulls -7.0
LA Clippers 7.0
O/U: 227.5

Spread: 
Boston Celtics 7.5
Detroit Pistons -7.5
O/U: 212.0

Spread: 
Denver Nuggets 12.0
Oklahoma City Thunder -12.0
O/U: 222.5

Spread: 
Utah Jazz 2.5
Milwaukee Bucks -2.5
O/U: 234.5

Spread: 
Los Angeles Lakers 7.0
Memphis Grizzlies -7.0
O/U: 218.5

Spread: 
Portland Trail Blazers 3.5
Cleveland Cavaliers -3.5
O/U: 222.0

Spread: 
Sacramento Kings 8.5
Orlando Magic -8.5
O/U: 223.5
```